# importrange on google shhet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

I have a question regarding the `importrange()` function. This is my formula:

`=ImportRange("1u0TjjekVHHb6shYiSWoo0W1ygxuSu2tVvLstnEE1NFo";"Juillet!I5")`

I have about 20 rows of data in the `Juillet` sheet. In order to quickly change the sheet in all the formulas, is it possible to get the sheet name in this formula through a reference to a cell?

For example, let's say that cell A1 contains a month name like `Juillet` or `Novembre`. How can I get the value in cell `A1` embedded in an `importrange()` formula?

What I would like to do is something like this:

=ImportRange("1u0TjjekVHHb6shYiSWoo0W1ygxuSu2tVvLstnEE1NFo";"`A1`!I5")

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there. You can put all data in tabs in the same spreadsheet file. Explain clearly whether the data is actually in separate spreadsheet files or all in the same spreadsheet file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to `importrange()` is just a text string, so you can concatenate the sheet name and the range reference like this:

`=importrange("1u0TjjekVHHb6shYiSWoo0W1ygxuSu2tVvLstnEE1NFo"; A1 & "!I5")`

One would usually get a *range of cells* with an `importrange()` formula rather than getting just a *single cell*. You may want to replace `I5` with something like `I5:K42`.

If the source data is stored in tabs in the same spreadsheet file, and the target sheet is in the same spreadsheet file as well, do not use `importrange()` but the `indirect()` function or an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276).

Comment: thanks a lot... I've try with A1 + "!K5", but doesn't work :)

Comment: Instead of `A1 + "!K5"`, use `A1 & "!K5"`.

Comment: yep.... i have tried and not i've try. After your comment I tried with `&` and you saved my life